# 100% body height in landscape overflows due to button bar

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari

Consider the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body
        {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Load it into safari on the iPhone. The page renders at 100% height. Now turn the iPhone to landscape and drag the page upwards. The (bottom) button bar appears and now we're scrolling the page up and down by the amount that the button bar offsets the content. No longer is the page height 100%, and content that should be visible is underneath the button bar, and a vertical scrollbar is evident.

Is it possible to eliminate this annoyance and get **true** 100% height?

Comment: Do you always want it to be 100% height in landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this by a `meta` directive in the head section that makes the appearance of the bottom button bar considerably less aggressive. Notice the last part (`minimal-ui`)

```
<meta name="viewport" 
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

Comment: It's not working anymore [since iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to add a class to `html` if it is an iPhone:

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))) {
     $('html').addClass('iphone');
}
```

Then try making its position as fixed, but only for when the orientation is in landscape, like so:

```
@media (orientation:landscape) {
    html.iphone > body {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width:100%;
        height: 480px !important;    /* pretty sure its 480px? */
    }
}
```